# How should I ask Angular questions providing a runnable sample?

Tags: support

I have an issue that I need to ask about, but I can't use jsFiddle, because it doesn't have Angular there. So it's a bit hard to replicate the problem in that environment.

Is there something similar to it, but for Angular?

Comment: don't (you but also the next users that will read this) forget to provide the relevant portion of code in your question so your question will still stand on its own after the plunkr will expire.

Comment: @Walfrat "Relevant portion" is a bit tricky because I have no idea where the error occurs. It unfolds my menu by hamburger click when I make the browser smaller but a second click doesn't fold it. And I'm not even sure if it's something with Angular or Bootstrap... So that might be hard to provide, hehe.

Comment: @KonradViltersten And yet it's necessary.  You need to provide a *minimal* reproducible example for the question to be appropriate on SO.  Dumping your whole code base because you can't be bothered to remove unnecessary code isn't acceptable.

Comment: @KonradViltersten THen maybe the chat will be a better place to ask :)

Comment: @Servy You seem to be making an incorrect assumption that I haven't bothered preparing. I find it a bit offensive. Also, as I said - I don't know which part is relevant as it's a bit about diagnostics and I might be mistaken on where I look.

Comment: @Walfrat The chat? Not sure what you mean. Is there a chat where I can ask my question or are you saying that I should ask the question and hope that someone will chat?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'm under the impression that you haven't actually asked the question yet, so no, I'm not assuming you haven't bothered preparing.  I'm saying if you end up, in the future, just dumping the whole thing instead of taking the time to narrow down the problem to a small reproducible example, *then* you'll have not properly prepared, and I'm saying this so that you *won't* do that and so that you *will* prepare appropriately before you post your question.  So again, if you don't know what's relevant then *figure out* what's relevant before posting your question.

Comment: @Servy I don't find your comment helpful and I'm not going to engage in a discussion that risks to get infected. If you have a suggestion on how to approach my problem, you're welcome to do so. Simply reiterating what's appropriate on SO or implying that I could "dump whole code base" doesn't achieve that goal. In fact, it's offensive. I reported your comment as not "Be Nice" and I strongly urge you to let it go. It's been less than pleasant and I wish not to engage further.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You said that you have no idea what the relevant code is, and don't think that you're going to be able to figure it out.  That means that you are either planning on posting your code *without* having figured out what's relevant, or that you're not planning on posting it at all.  I made sure that you were aware that it's important for you to figure out what the relevant code is before posting it.  If you already knew that you shouldn't be posting your question without figuring out the relevant code, then consider it useful information for any future readers of this question.

Comment: @Servy I find your comments offensive and your assumptions incorrect. In order not to be provoked I urge you again to please let it go. I noted your remarks and I feel that this discussion isn't contributing to SO. In my opinion, it should be ended now. I wish you a pleasant day.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You're offended at being informed of what's appropriate?  Why do you find that offensive?  You find the very idea of knowing the rules to be offensive?  *I* find that offensive.  You're worried about being provided into...knowing how to ask a good question, and avoiding posting a bad question?  You're trying to urge me into not helping people understand how to post an appropriate question?  And you think that's not contributing to SO?

Comment: @Servy I'm offended by the way your comment was formulated, not the content of what it actually conveys. It's simply the tone of those remarks that I find arrogant and unpleasant /YMMV of course). I'm not urging you to stop helping. I'm asking you to word your help in a more polite and humble way (not sure if it's the correct word). I asked here on Meta **because** I want to avoid bad questions. I don't see any implication to self-introspection and improvement on your part and I wish not to continue this conversation. Please accept my apology if I offended you, though. Wasn't my intention. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Angular questions, most of the people are using [plunkr](https://plnkr.co).

There is an option available for Angular:

[image]

Comment: Oh, boy... I just realized that setting up all the files will take forever... But I guess it's the way to get help...   :(